# Trying to create code that both verifies that a variable is numbers and has 4 or 5 characters long

Tags: python

I am trying to create code that takes a ZIP code and verifies that the input is numeric and that it's between 4 to 5 characters in length.  This is the code I am trying to use.   But if I put in letters, it doesn't print "Invalid Area Code", it just errors out.

```
zip_code = int(input("Please enter your area code: "))
if len(zip_code) == 4 or len(area_code) == 5 and zip_code.isnumeric(): 
    print (zip_code)
else:
     print("Invalid zip Code")
```

Comment: Don't convert the input to an `int`, work with the input as a string

Comment: What number do you think `int(“garbage”)` should be?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You're converting the input to an integer, then calling `len()` on it. You can call `len()` on strings, but not integers, so don't transform the input to an integer.
2. `area_code` isn't defined. You're probably looking to use `zip_code` instead.

Here is a code snippet that resolves both of these issues:

```py
zip_code = input("Please enter your area code: ")
if len(zip_code) == 4 or len(zip_code) == 5 and zip_code.isnumeric(): 
    print(zip_code)
else:
    print("Invalid ZIP code")
```

Answer (score 0):

If a string is parsable to be an integer, meaning that it is actually a number, your code will work fine. But most of the time, user inputs can not be predicted. if you just use `isnumeric` or `isdigit` in your code, you won't have any problem.

Personally speaking, I use regex to validate user input in most of the cases. In your case, I came up with code below:

```py
import re
string = input("Please enter your area code: ")
pattern = "^\d{4,5}$"
if re.search(pattern, string):
  print("Valid " + string)
else:
  print("Invalid zip Code")
```

Example of correct input:

```
1234
```

Output

```
Valid 1234
```

Example of incorrect input:

```
123415
```

Output:

```
Invalid zip Code
```

##### Explanation

`re.search` function takes two arguments. The first argument is a pattern which will check if the second argument, which is a string, follows the pattern or not. `^\d{4,5}$` checks if the user input is a number that has 4 or 5 digits.